# Print to console while getting user input from Scanner

Tags: java, io, console, java.util.scanner

I'm writing a server program that needs to print information, such as clients connecting or disconnecting, to the console while requesting user input through the `java.util.Scanner` class.  The user input would be a command such as "quit".

Is there a way to wait for user input while still printing information using `System.out.println()`? If I can't do this with `Scanner` and `System.out.println()` is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate your processing from your accepting of new connections.

Here is a trivial (and somewhat contrived) example

```
private static final class Handler implements Runnable {

    private final Socket socket;

    public Handler(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do stuff.
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
    final ExecutorService handlerExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    while (true) {
        final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Got new connection, passing off to handler");
        handlerExecutor.execute(new Handler(socket));
    }

}
```

So the main `Thread` deals only with accepting a connection and passing it off to the `handlerExecutor` which calls the `run` method of the `Handler`. This means that the server can carry on waiting for new connections and logging them while work goes on in the individual connections in their assigned `Handler`.